# Replacing derby.jar from Oracle with derby.jar from Apache

Tags: derby, javadb

Short version:  Can I replace the derby.jar that came with my JDK (from Oracle) with the latest derby.jar from Apache?

Long version:  I've been using the Java DB (Oracle's supported distribution of the Apache Derby open source database) that comes with the JDK for a few years.  I just found out that Apache still does regular updates to the Derby database libraries, the lastest one from June 2012 is [here](http://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.9.1.0.cgi).  The latest one contains some features I would like to use.

But is the Oracle derby.jar interchangeable with the Apache derby.jar?

Comment: [Java DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) is Oracle's supported distribution of the Apache Derby... Yes you can! But maybe you will not have anymore Oracle support, if you already have subscribed some tickets.

Comment: @ThierryB: Thanks.  I can live with that I think.

Comment: [@JohnFitzpatrick](http://stackoverflow.com/users/502556/john-fitzpatrick) ok, good travel in the air without oracle net :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have few problems, but note that this will count as an upgrade, so you should spend a bit of time reading http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/devguide/cdevupgrades.html and get comfortable with the concepts of "soft" and "hard" upgrades.

That is, if you truly want the two jars to be "interchangeable", meaning that you want to use the newer version of Derby, then go back to the older one, then make sure you only do a soft upgrade, since once you have done a hard upgrade you can't go back to the older version.

Myself, I would say, switch to the newer Apache derby.jar, do a hard upgrade of your existing databases, and plan **not** to go back to the older version of Derby.